# Heroku page is blank after deployment of react app

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, deployment

I have uploaded my react app on heroku by GitHub but problem here is it shows blank page after refreshing every 2 sec.

Here is link of Newsmoneky- https://news-app-8.herokuapp.com/#/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have the link for your GitHub repository?